# Is there a good erc20 source using web3js?

Tags: solidity, web3js, truffle, erc-20

I'm looking for some source codes using web3js for interaction with erc20 tokens and contracts.
Does anyone know good source codes using web3js?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although, it is really easy to interact with source code via [Truffle](https://truffleframework.com/), and you can find various tutorial such as [this](https://medium.com/@JusDev1988/build-your-own-token-81e8eeb94740), and many more on medium.

But if you really want to use just web3js then here is a github [link](https://github.com/StephenGrider/EthereumCasts/tree/master/inbox). Although this is complete ethereum cast. But you can get the idea from the `Inbox` contract. The `contract` directory have an `inbox.sol` contract. `compile.js` compiles the contract by `solc` compiler and exports. `deploy.js` is deploying the compiled contract to rinkebey testnet (You can also deploy locally by using Ganache). Lastly, the `inbox.test.js` inside the `test` directory contains the code to interact with contract by web3js.

Hope it will help.